# mod_proxy / proxypass error

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

I´ve the following error with mod_proxy and proxypass directive:

My vhost file:

```
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so


    <VirtualHost *:80>
    #ForensicLog logs/debuglog
    ServerName updatefw.example.com
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    ErrorLog logs/updatefw-error.log
    CustomLog logs/updatefw-access_log common
    ProxyPass / balancer://test
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://test

    <Proxy balancer://test>
      BalancerMember http://10.10.20.12:80
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

When i browse updatefw.example.com i get a 200 from index file:

```
[root@10.10.20.12 updatefw.example.com]# pwd
/var/www/vhosts/updatefw.example.com
[root@10.10.20.12 updatefw.example.com]# cat index.html

OK
```

However when i try to browse a file in a subdirectory i get a 500 error:

http://updatefw.example.com/pepe/asdf.txt

```
/var/www/vhosts/updatefw.example.com/pepe
[root@10.10.20.12 pepe]# ls
asdf.txt
```

error log:

```
[Wed Apr 20 11:43:53.046606 2016] [proxy:warn] [pid 27551] [client 10.20.1.1:56553] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /pepe/asdf.txt. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I´ve no idea what is going wrong since i´m loading mod proxy http module.
Brosing http://10.10.20.12/pepe/asdf.txt works fine

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://test/

ProxyPassReverse / balancer://test/
```

Needed a / behind balancer name.